# How to combine and map observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an observable that streams the current view state (ngrx) which is a list of objects:

```
this.store.pipe(select('objects'))
```

and another observable that retrieves the index part of the current URL parameters:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.switchMap(params => params['index'])
```

How can I combine these to give me an observable that streams the object at the current index (`objects[index]`) if the index is valid?

Comment: Have you checked Observable.forkJoin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html)?

```
this.store.pipe(select('objects')).combineLatest(
  this.activatedRoute.params.map(params => params['index']).filter(index => !isNaN(index)),
  (objects, index) => objects[parseInt(index)]
).filter(object => object !== undefined);
```

Answer (score 1):

its better to use selectors!
In that case no need to combine observables and pretty easy too.

you can create a new selector by combining existing selector;

create a new selector using first and second observables selector; then select only one

below example im passing data and sort paramter and generating data in sort order as new selector

```
export const getDataByOrder = createSelector(
  getAllData,
  getSortParameters,
  (data, sortBy) => {
    let sortData = (a: Data, b: Data) =>
      a[sortBy.orderBy].toLowerCase() < b[sortBy.orderBy].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
    let sorted = data.sort(sortData);
    if (sortBy.direction === 'DESC') {
      sorted = sorted.reverse();
    }
    return sorted;
  }
);
```